# WCF Handling of Large Files

Tags: c#, wcf, large-files

All the posts and search results that I've reviewed regarding WCF and uploading of large files have pretty much have the same answers for increasing the maximums like *maxReceivedMessageSize*. That's great I guess if you're just trying to get it working, but what if you have an actual maximum that you want to enforce. How do you handle that better?

Currently the client gets a System.ServiceModel.EndpointNotFoundException
saying, "There was no endpoint listening", inner exception "The remote server returned an error: (404) Not Found." How could I catch this in my service and return a better error message? Like "File exceeds maximum allowable size"

Comment: It seems you are looking for this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/13900704/920557.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass your file as a `Stream` parameter to your service method. Doing so allows to dynamically check the file size without processing it entirely (one should set here some sane *maxReceivedMessageSize* which shouldn't be exceeded in the most of real-world cases).

Here is an example of RESTful WCF service:

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IFileService
{
    [OperationContract, WebInvoke(Method = "POST", UriTemplate = "/ProcessFile")]
    string ProcessFile(Stream file);
}

public class FileService : IFileService
{
    public string ProcessFile(Stream file)
    {
        const int bufferLength = 32;
        const int maxSize = 256;
        var buffer = new byte[bufferLength];
        int bytesRead, totalBytesRead = 0;

        do
        {
            bytesRead = file.Read(buffer, 0, bufferLength);
            totalBytesRead += bytesRead;

            if (totalBytesRead > maxSize)
                return $"File is too large - maximum {maxSize} bytes allowed.";
        }
        while (bytesRead > 0);

        return $"Total {totalBytesRead} bytes read.";
    }
}
```

Here is a sample code for hosting this service:

```
var host = new ServiceHost(typeof(FileService));

host.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(IFileService),
    new WebHttpBinding { TransferMode = TransferMode.StreamedRequest },
    "http://localhost:8080")
    .EndpointBehaviors.Add(new WebHttpBehavior());

host.Open();

Console.WriteLine("The host is opened. Press ENTER to exit...");
Console.ReadLine();

host.Close();
```

Note that one needs `TransferMode = TransferMode.StreamedRequest` to be able to process large files - see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1519512/how-to-send-large-file-from-client-to-server-using-wcf) for details.

Comment: Is passing it as a stream the only way to handle this?

Comment: @AdrianP it's the only way I know.